# Create a status bar with flags in Java

Tags: java, swing

I want to have  Status bar in my application which can be bound with media time duration and if a user wants to select a time duration then he can select a time duration on that Status bar. also want to show the selected duration with two flags. have no clue how to made this program. have searched a lot but didn't find anything relative. Please help me.

[image: Progressbar with flag]

```
public class Statusbar
{
    public Statusbar()
    {
        //take somethink like JProgressBar
        //bind the media length on it
        //and set flags on it..i don't know how to set this flags..!!
    }
}
```

Comment: [SwingX](http://java.net/projects/swingx/downloads/directory/releases) has JXMultiThumbSlider which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: You might also like to have a look at the [`RangeSlider`](http://harmoniccode.blogspot.com.au/2011/11/friday-fun-component-xiv.html)

Comment: Thanks, that's fulfilling my requirements, but core java swing don't have any predefined Class for this purpose???

Comment: If it did, I would have linked to it instead and the Internet wouldn't be proliferated with requests for one or examples of how to achieve it :P